# error about context FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK

Tags: java, android, pdf

In my application, I have an expandablelistview and I want to open a PDF downloaded from the internet when I click on a specific child. When I click on it, the app crashes and this error appears on Android Monitor on Android Studio:

> Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?

When I try to addflag() or setflag() it tells me something about static context.

ContextGetter Class:

```
public class ContextGetter extends Application {
    private static Context context;

    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
        context = getApplicationContext();
    }

    public static Context getAppContext() {
        return context;
    }
}
```

Downloader Class:

```
public class Downloader {
    public static void DownloadFile(String fileURL, File directory) {
        try {
            FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(directory);
            URL u = new URL(fileURL);
            HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
            c.setRequestMethod("GET");
            c.setDoOutput(true);
            c.connect();

            InputStream in = c.getInputStream();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int len1 = 0;
            while ((len1 = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                f.write(buffer, 0, len1);
            }
            f.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

OpenPDF (AbrirPDF in my language) class:

```
public class AbrirPDF {
    public static void showPdf() {
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+"lightflow/Read.pdf");
        PackageManager packageManager = ContextGetter.getAppContext().getPackageManager();
        Intent testIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        testIntent.setType("application/pdf");
        List list = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(testIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
        ContextGetter.getAppContext().startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Part of the Activity Java code:

```
private void registerClick() {
    expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                    int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            if ((groupPosition == 0) && (childPosition == 0)) {
                File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+"IAVE", "Read.pdf");
                try {
                    file.createNewFile();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                Downloader.DownloadFile("MY_URL", file);


                AbrirPDF.showPdf();
            } else {

            }

            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Due to starting another application Activity from your application, so add NEW_TASK flag with Intent as `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);`

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя It worked. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using the application context you must set this flag on your intent

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

If you do not want to use that flag and keep using the current task you would need to add an `Activity` parameter to your `showPdf()` method and use that to start the next activity instead.

```
public static void showPdf(Activity activity) {
    ...
    activity.startActivity(intent);
}
```

You can then call it from your `onChildClick` handler using:

```
AbrirPDF.showPdf(MyActivityClassName.this);
```